# Specific Date/Time Picker in android UI?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, mobile, calendar

Is there any calendar model in which using in Android APP and have following capability?

> 1- Can select multiple day range from different month. for example Nov 5-8, Jan 7-9. Or can we select Jan (all days), March (add days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. You can implement it yourself or use this library: https://github.com/savvisingh/DateRangePicker

Comment: Is there any capability to select June(all days) and July (all days) for example by one click?